# How to find the index of current object in range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, iterator

Assume I have the following code:

```
vector<int> list;
for(auto& elem:list) {
    int i = elem;
}
```

Can I find the position of `elem` in the vector without maintaining a separate iterator?

Comment: That's not what range-based for is for (heh, is that a pun?)

Comment: This is not possible in STL containers, unless using `std::find` or some other overkill function. You can't conclude iterators from contained elements. Why not maintain an iterator?

Comment: For two reasons. The first is all I want to do (in this case) is see whether I'm at the last element or not :) and the second is that the compiler must be maintaining one, why can't I access it? "this" is a variable with scope maintained by the compiler, why not here? Or provide an alternative (but still convenient) syntax that, as javascript does, sets up a variable that changes as the you go through the loop. for(auto& index:list)

Comment: @FredFinkle you are actually correct, [there is an iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), but when using a range based `for` loop, it is a compiler-internal name and can therefore not be used in your code. So if you really want to know if you're at the last element, you should use the `for(;;)` loop.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/28769156/364696](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28769156/364696)

Comment: The header-only [cppitertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools) library implements this.

Comment: [std::views::enumerate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) is a C++23 solution.

Answer (score 70):

Yes you can, it just take some massaging ;)

The trick is to use composition: instead of iterating over the container directly, you "zip" it with an index along the way.

Specialized zipper code:

```
template <typename T>
struct iterator_extractor { typedef typename T::iterator type; };

template <typename T>
struct iterator_extractor<T const> { typedef typename T::const_iterator type; };


template <typename T>
class Indexer {
public:
    class iterator {
        typedef typename iterator_extractor<T>::type inner_iterator;

        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<inner_iterator>::reference inner_reference;
    public:
        typedef std::pair<size_t, inner_reference> reference;

        iterator(inner_iterator it): _pos(0), _it(it) {}

        reference operator*() const { return reference(_pos, *_it); }

        iterator& operator++() { ++_pos; ++_it; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp(*this); ++*this; return tmp; }

        bool operator==(iterator const& it) const { return _it == it._it; }
        bool operator!=(iterator const& it) const { return !(*this == it); }

    private:
        size_t _pos;
        inner_iterator _it;
    };

    Indexer(T& t): _container(t) {}

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(_container.begin()); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(_container.end()); }

private:
    T& _container;
}; // class Indexer

template <typename T>
Indexer<T> index(T& t) { return Indexer<T>(t); }
```

And using it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// Zipper code here

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (auto p: index(v)) {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

You can see it at [ideone](http://ideone.com/rAcaZ), though it lacks the for-range loop support so it's less pretty.

**EDIT:**

Just remembered that I should check Boost.Range more often. Unfortunately no `zip` range, but I did found a pearl: [`boost::adaptors::indexed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html). However it requires access to the iterator to pull of the index. Shame :x

Otherwise with the [`counting_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html) and a generic `zip` I am sure it could be possible to do something interesting...

In the ideal world I would imagine:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (auto tuple: zip(iota(0), v)) {
        std::cout << tuple.at<0>() << ": " << tuple.at<1>() << "\n";
    }
}
```

With `zip` automatically creating a view as a range of tuples of references and `iota(0)` simply creating a "false" range that starts from `0` and just counts toward infinity (or well, the maximum of its type...).

Comment: How about `counting_range` (or [`boost::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html)) + [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)?

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, Boost.Iterators has the building blocks (it seems), however there is no corresponding range, which is annoying.

Comment: @Xeo Your version works fine for lvalues (indeed as you said no copies take place). For rvalues there is some problem, though. I have not spotted it yet, but I will continue to look into it tomorrow. Basically, when I use `index` like this `for (auto x : index(std::vector<int>{2, 4, 6})) { ... }` I get this error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘Indexer<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::iterator::iterator(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator)’`. I used g++-4.7.

Comment: @betabandido: Yeah, that's why I didn't roll back yet and asked for Matthieu to join me in the Lounge, to discuss that exact problem. `begin` and `end` are `const`, and if the original argument is an rvalue, `_container` is a value type and is also `const`, making `_container.begin()` and `_container.end()` return `const_iterator`s instead of the wanted `iterator`s. One solution is to add non-`const` `begin` and `end` functions to the `Indexer`.

Comment: @Xeo: sorry but my hours differ slightly from yours it seems. Indeed in this case I think that removing the `const` from `begin` and `end` would be the right thing to do.

Comment: You were on the right track. See my answer for a full use of  `boost::adaptors::indexed` together with a performance evaluation.

Comment: I really like this idiomatic solution!

Answer (score 37):

jrok is right : range-based for loops are not designed for that purpose.

However, in your case it is possible to compute it using pointer arithmetic since `vector` stores its elements contiguously (*)

```
vector<int> list;
for(auto& elem:list) { 
    int i = elem;
    int pos = &elem-&list[0]; // pos contains the position in the vector 

    // also a &-operator overload proof alternative (thanks to ildjarn) :
    // int pos = addressof(elem)-addressof(list[0]); 

}
```

But this is clearly a bad practice since it obfuscates the code & makes it more fragile (it easily breaks if someone changes the container type, overload the `&` operator or replace 'auto&' by 'auto'. good luck to debug that!)

NOTE: Contiguity is guaranteed for vector in C++03, and array and string in C++11 standard.

Comment: Yes it is stated in the standard. Contiguity is guaranteed for `vector` in C++03, and `array` and `string` in C++11.

Comment: "*it easily breaks if someone ... overload the `&` operator*" That's what `std::addressof` is for. :-]

Comment: You're right. So the &-overload proof version would be : int pos = addressof(elem)- addressof(list[0]);  .... Matthieu M.'s iterator wrapper is way better :)

Comment: Didn't know that contiguity was guaranteed. Wouldn't want to use it here, but good to know.

Comment: Why not use std::distance to figure out the position?

Answer (score 23):

No, you can't (at least, not without effort). If you need the position of an element, you shouldn't use range-based for. Remember that it's just a convenience tool for the most common case: execute some code for each element. In the less-common circumstances where you need the position of the element, you have to use the less-convenient regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 22):

Based on the answer from @Matthieu there is a very elegant solution using the mentioned [boost::adaptors::indexed](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html):

```
std::vector<std::string> strings{10, "Hello"};
int main(){
    strings[5] = "World";
    for(auto const& el: strings| boost::adaptors::indexed(0))
      std::cout << el.index() << ": " << el.value() << std::endl;
}
```

[You can try it](https://ideone.com/JDjsTB)

This works pretty much like the "ideal world solution" mentioned, has pretty syntax and is concise. Note that the type of `el` in this case is something like `boost::foobar<const std::string&, int>`, so it handles the reference there and no copying is performed. It is even incredibly efficient: https://godbolt.org/g/e4LMnJ (The code is equivalent to keeping an own counter variable which is as good as it gets)

For completeness the alternatives:

```
size_t i = 0;
for(auto const& el: strings) {
  std::cout << i << ": " << el << std::endl;
  ++i;
}
```

Or using the contiguous property of a vector:

```
for(auto const& el: strings) {
  size_t i = &el - &strings.front();
  std::cout << i << ": " << el << std::endl;
}
```

The first generates the same code as the boost adapter version (optimal) and the last is 1 instruction longer: https://godbolt.org/g/nEG8f9

Note: If you only want to know, if you have the last element you can use:

```
for(auto const& el: strings) {
  bool isLast = &el == &strings.back();
  std::cout << isLast << ": " << el << std::endl;
}
```

This works for every standard container but `auto&`/`auto const&` must be used (same as above) but that is recommended anyway. Depending on the input this might also be pretty fast (especially when the compiler knows the size of your vector)

Replace the `&foo` by `std::addressof(foo)` to be on the safe side for generic code.

Comment: I added the 2 alternatives with godbolt comparison of the generated code for completeness and also addressed the need of the OP (in the comments) for detecting the last element

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: Instead of `strings |  boost::adaptors::indexed(0)` one can also use `boost::adaptors::index(strings)`.  The outcome is the same but IMO it is a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a compiler with C++14 support you can do it in a functional style:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void for_enum(T& container, std::function<void(int, typename T::value_type&)> op)
{
    int idx = 0;
    for(auto& value : container)
        op(idx++, value);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> sv {"hi", "there"};
    for_enum(sv, [](auto i, auto v) {
        std::cout << i << " " << v << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Works with clang 3.4 and gcc 4.9 (not with 4.8); for both need to set `-std=c++1y`. The reason you need c++14 is because of the `auto` parameters in the lambda function.

Comment: `std::function` uses type erasure which is expensive.  Why not use `template<typename T, typename Callable>
void for_enum(T& container, Callable op)` so you don't have to pay for type erasure?

Answer (score 8):

There is a surprisingly simple way to do this

```
vector<int> list;
for(auto& elem:list) {
    int i = (&elem-&*(list.begin()));
}
```

where `i` will be your required index.

This takes advantage of the fact that [C++ vectors are always contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609169/are-c-vectors-always-contiguous).

Answer (score 7):

If you insist on using range based for, and to know index, it is pretty trivial to maintain index as shown below.
I do not think there is a cleaner / simpler solution for range based for loops. But really why not use a standard for(;;)? That probably would make your intent and code the clearest.

```
vector<int> list;
int idx = 0;
for(auto& elem:list) {
    int i = elem;
    //TODO whatever made you want the idx
    ++idx;
}
```

Comment: (idx amounts to "maintaining a separate iterator")

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quite beautiful solution using c++20:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template<typename T>
struct EnumeratedElement {
    std::size_t index;
    T& element;
};

auto enumerate(std::ranges::range auto& range) 
    -> std::ranges::view auto 
{
    return range | std::views::transform(
        [i = std::size_t{}](auto& element) mutable {
            return EnumeratedElement{i++, element};
        }
    );
}

auto main() -> int {
    auto const elements = std::array{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2};
    for (auto const [index, element] : enumerate(elements)) {
        std::cout << "Element " << index << ": " << element << '\n';
    }
}
```

The major features used here are c++20 ranges, c++20 concepts, c++11 mutable lambdas, c++14 lambda capture initializers, and c++17 structured bindings. Refer to cppreference.com for information on any of these topics.

Note that `element` in the structured binding is in fact a reference and not a copy of the element (not that it matters here). This is because any qualifiers around the `auto` only affect a temporary object that the fields are extracted from, and not the fields themselves.

The generated code is identical to the code generated by this (at least by gcc 10.2):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

auto main() -> int {
    auto const elements = std::array{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2};
    for (auto index = std::size_t{}; auto& element : elements) {
        std::cout << "Element " << index << ": " << element << '\n';
        index++;
    }
}
```

Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/a5bfxz

Comment: OMG, what is happening to the C/C++ I grew up with? This is nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: C++98 is not the same language as C++20. Rust is incomprehensible by someone who only knows C.

Comment: Perhaps I've been programming in C, C++03 (and more recently C++11) for too long, but these lambdas, new obscure `auto main() -> int` syntax, type deduction with `auto` and so on is turning a once clean and beautiful language into a Rube Goldberg mess. Very clever, super impressive...and nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: It is a matter of what you're used to. This is more comprehensible to me because this is the code I've written for the past year. I have chosen what features to use and when based purely on reasoning about safety and utility. For me it's like learning a new language with potential of better performance, safety and simplicity (abstraction).

Comment: Why does adding a view filter to the container in your example result in the output indices becoming `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `9`, `11`, `13` (instead of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`)? Even a do-nothing filter has this effect. For example: `enumerate(elements) | std::views::filter([](auto const &) { return true; })`

Comment: @Spire This is probably because the begin iterator in ``filter_view`` is precalculated with ``find_if``, causing an initial dreference. The index is incremented every time the dereference operator is used on iterators from this enumerate function. A better method would be to write our own enumerate view class that only increments the index when the increment operator is called. Another alternative could be to use ``std::views::iota`` together with ``std::views::transform`` and restricting the function to random access ranges or something similar.

Comment: Not implemented in Clang [as of now](https://godbolt.org/z/rqzsdjWx7).  MSVC [works](https://godbolt.org/z/qv1q87bxq).

Answer (score 2):

I read from your comments that one reason you want to know the index is to know if the element is the first/last in the sequence. If so, you can do

```
for(auto& elem:list) {
//  loop code ...
    if(&elem == &*std::begin(list)){ ... special code for first element ... }
    if(&elem == &*std::prev(std::end(list))){ ... special code for last element ... }
//  if(&elem == &*std::rbegin(list)){... (C++14 only) special code for last element ...}
//  loop code ... 
}
```

**EDIT:** For example, this prints a container skipping a separator in the last element. Works for most containers I can imagine (including arrays), (online demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bdce059abd87f91):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

template<class Container>
void print(Container const& c){
  for(auto& x:c){
    std::cout << x; 
    if(&x != &*std::prev(std::end(c))) std::cout << ", "; // special code for last element
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> v{1.,2.,3.};
  print(v); // prints 1,2,3
  std::list<double> l{1.,2.,3.};
  print(l); // prints 1,2,3
  std::initializer_list<double> i{1.,2.,3.};
  print(i); // prints 1,2,3
  std::set<double> s{1.,2.,3.};
  print(s); // print 1,2,3
  double a[3] = {1.,2.,3.}; // works for C-arrays as well
  print(a); // print 1,2,3
}
```

Comment: Please note (before unjustified downvoting) that the author of the question is asking this in the context of detecting the last element in a for-ranged loop for a container. For that I see no reason why comparing `&elem` and `&*std::prev(std::end(list))` will not work or be practical. I agree with the other answer that an iterator-based for is more appropriate for this, but still.

Comment: It seems easier to declare `int i=c.size();` before the loop and test `if(--i==0)`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, the `int i` code was just an example. I will remove it to avoid confusion. Even if you use `size` before the loop you will need a counter.

Answer (score 2):

Tobias Widlund wrote a nice MIT licensed Python style header only enumerate (C++17 though):

[GitHub](https://github.com/therocode/enumerate/blob/master/enumerate.hpp)

[Blog Post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506120522/https://blog.therocode.net/2018/10/for-each-with-index)

Really nice to use:

```
std::vector<int> my_vector {1,3,3,7};

for(auto [i, my_element] : en::enumerate(my_vector))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: A more popular (and feature-rich) version is [CPP-Itertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::views::enumerate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) (C++23) to get the index of elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    const auto letters = std::vector{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
 
    for (const auto& [index, letter] : std::views::enumerate(letters))
    {
        std::cout << '(' << index << ':' << letter << ") ";
    }
}
```

Check the [C++ 23 compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) page to see if your compiler supports this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro-based solution that probably beats most others on simplicity, compile time, and code generation quality:

```
#include <iostream>

#define fori(i, ...) if(size_t i = -1) for(__VA_ARGS__) if(i++, true)

int main() {
    fori(i, auto const & x : {"hello", "world", "!"}) {
        std::cout << i << " " << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$ g++ -o enumerate enumerate.cpp -std=c++11 && ./enumerate 
0 hello
1 world
2 !
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid having to write an auxiliary function while having
the index variable local to the loop, you can use a lambda with a mutable variable.:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<char> values = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    std::for_each(begin(values), end(values), [i = size_t{}] (auto x) mutable {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << x << '\n';
        ++i;
    });
}
```