# Is there a way to get element position from within a lambda passed to sort?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Lets assume I call sort with a lambda like this, with `nearPoints` being a vector of points in 3D.

```
sort(nearPoints.begin(), nearPoints.end(),
     [srcPoint](const kd_point &A, const kd_point &B)
     {return Distance(srcPoint, A) < Distance(srcPoint, B); });
```

In order to save on redundant calls to `Distance`, I would like to pre-calculate the values, and have the call to sort use them.

The elegant solution is, IMHO, to prep a second vector with distances, read it in the lambda, and switch elements as necessary.

My problem is how to find `A`'s and `B`'s indexes in `nearPoints`, so I would know which elements to access in the second vector. Is there a way to do it?

---

I know I can make a new vector with each elements containing a point and its distance from `srcPoint`, but that would require populating the new vector before the sort, and extracting the points back in the right order after the sort, which strikes me as inelegant.

Comment: The solution in your tagline seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: Well, the index is just `&a - nearPoints.data()`, but it is useless here since `sort` is going to be swapping the elements around all over the place.

Comment: If you want to speed this up, sort by distance-squared.  It'll give the same order, but the `sqrt` operation is by far the most expensive part of a euclidean distance calculation

Comment: Good starting points [are here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11329249/2642204) [and here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10962575/2642204).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, you can get the index:

```
  std::sort(std::begin(near_points), std::end(near_points),
      [src_point, &near_points](int const &a, int const &b){
        auto ia = &a - near_points.data();
        auto ib = &b - near_points.data();
        ...
        return ...;
      });
```

But this would be **useless**, as the elements are moved all the time by the sort.

What you could do instead is create a hash map map (`std::map` or `std::unordered_map`) of `<kd_point, int>` where you precompute the distances. You would have to **measure** though to see if it will be faster, as a map adds a considerable overhead, both in terms of space and time. The computation of `Distance()` would have to be very slow in order to justify this.

If the `Distance` is just an euclidean distance, the simple yet effective optimization you can do is this: Since all you do is compare the distances, **you don't need to compute the square root** (which is the most time consuming). So you have `SquareDist` where you just compute `(x2-x1)^2 + ...`. and the condition for the lambda becomes `SquareDist(src, a) < SquareDist(src, b)` You have to be careful not to overflow.