# C++ Version of Python-loop "for i, num in enumerate(list):"

Tags: python, c++, enums

In python, you can iterate a list like below. Is there a similarly short way of doing this in C++?

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i, num in enumerate(list):
     # do stuff
```

Something like `for(int num : list)` is close, but not the same.

Comment: Is this what you could use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328264/python-like-loop-enumeration-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**C++ 17 time!**

```
for(auto [it, i] = tuple{list.begin(), 0}; it != list.end(); it++, i++)
{
   cout << *it; //actual item
   cout << i; //index value
}
```