# How to remove the Nth element in a range?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

I can write:

```
my_range | ranges::views::remove(3)
```

using the ranges-v3 library, to remove the element(s) equal to 3 from the range `my_range`. This can also be done in C++20 with

```
my_range | std::views::filter([](auto const& val){ return val != 3; })
```

But - how can I remove the element at *position* 3 in `my_range`, keeping the elements at positions 0, 1, 2, 4, 5 etc.?

Comment: I made a rather dramatic edit to your question, to simplify it. Feel free to undo the change if you don't like it...

Comment: @einpoklum The [remove] tag you added is currently being burninated actually https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408573

Comment: @einpoklum `std::ranges::remove` is an algorithm, not a range adaptor - as you can tell from the fact that it's not in `views::`

Comment: @Barry: Right... but it still exists. Perhaps it should be mentioned in the question as well?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/drop.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>

int main() {
    const auto my_range = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
 
    auto index_to_drop = 3; // so drop the 40
    auto earlier = my_range | ranges::views::take(index_to_drop - 1);
    auto later = my_range | ranges::views::drop(index_to_drop);
    auto both = ranges::views::concat(earlier, later);
    for (auto const & num : both) { std::cout << num << ' '; }
}
```

This will produce:

```
10 20 30 50 60 70
```

... without the 40.

See it working on [<kbd>Godbolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/scsbTKoYh). Compilation time is extremely poor though. Also, `concat()` is not part of C++20. Maybe in C++23?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way I can think of in range-v3 would be:

```cpp
auto remove_at_index(size_t idx) {
    namespace rv = ranges::views;
    return rv::enumerate
         | rv::filter([=](auto&& pair){ return pair.first != idx; })
         | rv::values;
}
```

To be used like:

```cpp
my_range | remove_at_index(3);
```

`enumerate` (and its more general cousin `zip`) is not in C++20, but will hopefully be in C++23.

Comment: Thought about this, was reminded of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329249/1593077), but didn't remember it was easy with ranges-v3. Thanks and +1.

Comment: Please could you add an example about how this could be done with actions (if possible)? Thanks