# how to return index of element in vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, indexing

Given a vector

```
vector<classX *> myVec;
```

how to return the index `i` of one of its elements as in the following function;

```
size_t nearestElement(classY const& p){
     size_t i(0);
     double d = distance(myVec[i]->position(), p);
     for (auto const& element : myVec){
         if(distance(element->position(), p) < d){
            i = ???; // the index of the current element
         }
     return i;
     }
}
```

where `position()` is a function defined in `classX` and `distance` is not the `std::distance` function, but a function I defined my self.

Comment: You may be thinking about this too much; you're looping through the *indexes* - so you already have what you need

Comment: Use an index loop instead of the range loop and the problem will more or less solve itself.

Comment: yes it's easy like that, but isn't there anyway to return the index using the implementation above ?

Comment: you can find more on this here (actually this SO is duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962290/find-position-of-element-in-c11-range-based-for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change range based for to regular for, or add indexing variable to your current for:

```
int index = 0;
for (auto const& element : myVec){          
     if(distance(element->position(), p) < d){
        i = index; // the index of the current element
     }
     index++
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`&element - &myVec[0]` should do the trick for container with continuous data (as `std::vector`).

if your `distance` function is cheap, you may rewrite your function like this:

```
size_t nearestElement(classY const& p)
{
    auto it = std::min_element(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
        [&p](const classX* lhs, const classX* rhs) {
            return distance(lhs->position(), p) < distance(rhs->position(), p);
        });
    return it - myVec.begin(); // Will return 0 if myVec is empty.
}
```