# getting the current index from a for_each loop

Tags: c++, foreach

when working with a for loop such as this

```
for(int i=0 ; i<collection.size() ; i++)
{
  //current index is i and total size is size
}
```

However I have something like this

```
  for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [&](MyTuple& e)
        {
            //Total size would be collection.size()
            //How would i get the current index ?
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find position of element in C++11 range-based for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962290/find-position-of-element-in-c11-range-based-for-loop), not 100% the same but the principle perhaps is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put a counter variable above the loop, capture it in the lambda and increment it each time. As this is quite awkward, I suggest you don't use `for_each` when the index of the element is important (just my opinion).

```
size_t count = 0;
for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [&count](MyTuple& e)
{
    ...
    ++count;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was already thinking of doing that. Just wanted to know if there was a faster/right way

Answer (score 1):

Using the `std::for_each` algorithm on an iterator range won't give you the index without applying a special adapter to the iterators. However, using a vanilla `for` on an iterator range can give you the index like this:

```
for(auto it = collection.begin(); it != collection.end(); ++it)
{
    const auto index = std::distance(collection.begin(), it);
    ...
}
```

Note that `index` above is only meaningful with "index into an array"-semantics for random access iterators.

Comment: I would prefer to use `operator -` on the iterators, so that if they are not random-access, it won't compile, as distance could be slow.