# c++ Using bubble sort to custom sort a vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am stuck trying to bubble sort a `vector<vector<string>> vvs`
If running a for loop like

`for ( auto x : vvs )`
which contains a line like

```
if ( x.at(pos) == (*need next x position*).at(pos) {
    //perform sort and swap if needed
}
```

Is it possible to get the next position of the range based loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962290/find-position-of-element-in-c11-range-based-for-loop

Comment: That answers the question. I guess  I will go back and use an iterator based loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (auto i : o)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

range based for loop are used only for sequencing each element in an array or vector for customization loops used traditional for loop

```
for (unsigned i = 2; i != 10; ++i)
      std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using a vector, just use a `std::list`, Its much simpler and faster than manually doing it,

```
std::list<std::string> vvs;
```

And then to order the list its as easy as:

```
vvs.sort(compare_nocase);
```

To sort the list alphabetically, and not case specific;

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, define an iterator based `Bubble Sort` like

```
template <class Iterator>
inline void BubbleSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    for (Iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        for (Iterator j = begin; j < i; ++j)
            if (*i < *j)
                std::iter_swap(i, j);
}
```

To apply on your vector

```
for (auto & v : vvs) {
    BubbleSort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```