# Way to distinguish objects in C++

Tags: c++, oop

There is a structure, that an object belongs to. There are no functions for the stucture defined.
To list the objects I've used

`for (auto object:objects)`

But now I need to distinguish the objects to perform a different action on every 3rd object. How can I list them so I can tell which object is the 3rd?

Comment: You can either do it the [hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962290/find-position-of-element-in-c11-range-based-for-loop/43423278) or just use a conventional `for` loop with an index. You could also keep a separate counter on the side.

Comment: I can't understand the "There is a structure, that an object belongs to". Are you talking of a c-like array of objects, a STL collection? you need to explain this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop or a while loop. This way you will be able to use an index to know which object is every third one or nth one.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if(i % 3 == 0)
    {   
        objects[i] // do something with this object here
    }
}
```

Or if it objects is not accessible by []:

```
int i = 0;
// remove the & if you need to use a copy of the object
for(auto& object: objects) {
    if(i % 3 == 0)
    {   
        // do something with this object here
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: `objects` isn't said to be accessible by `operator[]`.

Comment: @superdeveloper thank you, I updated my answer to have an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`for (auto object: objects)` statement means that the data structure containing `objects` is iterable, meaning that `objects` data structure has implemented `begin()` and `end()` functions.
Now from what I understood you need to perform a particular action every 3 elements. The most simple ways to do it are:

- by using an additional counter:

```
size_t counter = 0;
for (auto object: objects) {
    if (counter % 3 == 0) {
        // modify object
    }
    counter ++;
}
```

Be aware that depending on the type objects data structure when invoking `for (auto object: objects)` you might actually do a copy. (not passing the object by reference). This is due to the fact that auto takes the declination type of the element stored in `objects` data structure. To make sure you really modify the object, one needs to specify that you pass the reference: `for (auto & object: objects)` for instance.

- by changing the for loop statement with iterators

```
for (auto it = objects.begin(); it != object.end(); it ++) {
    size_t element_position = std::distance(objects.begin(), it);
    if (element_position % 3 == 0) {
        // do something with * it which stores the object
    }
}
```

Be cautious that `std::distance` method might be linear in case that the iterator of the data structure is not a random access iterator.
For more details please have a look at:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/