# Regular for loop vs range for loop while dealing with indices of std::vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, stdvector

Since `C++11` there is a cool way to iterate through the containers using **for range loop**. This version is recommended by lots of `C++` gurus such as Herb Sutter, Scott Meyers, Jason Turner, etc. But suppose we need to extract the indices of the certain value of `std::vector`, so in that case what code snippet is preferable overall, taking into account all main criteria of `C++` good coding(readability, efficiency, memory, etc.)?

**Version 1:**

```
    for(size_t id = 0; id < myVec.size(); ++id) {
      //extracting indices with a certain value
    }
```

**or**

**Version 2:**

```
{
  size_t id = 0;
  for(auto& elem : myVec) {
    //extracting indices with a certain value
    ++id;
  }   
}
```

Comment: If you actually need the indices, don't use the range-based for. Pointless to reinvent the original style of the loop when it still works and is applicable to the code you want to write.

Comment: Probably opinion-based. But, if you have C++20 or later, you can use a "hybrid" form: `for (size_t id = 0; auto& elem : myVec) {`

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962290/how-to-find-the-index-of-current-object-in-range-based-for-loop) has some more suggestions how to do this, also in newer versions of C++.