# Operator *= overloading in C++

Tags: c++

The following code demonstrate simple operator overloading:

Class Position has 3 int field and a method to print them.

```
class Position
{

    private:
        int x,y,z;

    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout << x << "," << y << "," << z << endl;
        }

        Position (int a, int b, int c)
        : x(4),
        y(50),
        z(23)
        {
            x=a;
            y=b;
            z=c;
        }

        Position operator+(const Position &other);
        Position operator*=(const int &multi);
};
```

Operators + and *= are overloaded as such:

```
Position Position::operator+ (const Position &other)
{
    x = x + other.x;
    y = y + other.y;
    z = z + other.z;

    return *this;
}


Position Position::operator*= (const int &multi)
{
    x = x * multi;
    y = y * multi;
    z = z * multi;

    return *this;    
}
```

The code runs:

```
int main()
{
    Position p5( 1, 2, 3 );
    p5.print();

    Position p6( 4, 5, 6 );
    p6.print();

    Position p7 = p5 + p6;
    p7.print();

    p7 *= 2;
    p7.print();

    (p7 *= 2) *= 3;
    p7.print();
}
```

The result yielded are:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
5,7,9
10,14,18
20,28,36
```

Question is why won't the last result perform as it should when it is done in nested?

Comment: Because you return by value, not by reference.

Comment: What is the output if the last p7.print() line, you didn't include it.

Comment: Because you do not return `Position` by reference from `operator *=`.

Comment: Your binary `operator+` modifies the LHS operand. This is unlikely to be the desired behaviour.

Comment: See the Binary Arithmetic Operators section of this answer: [Common operators to overload](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/445976)

Comment: The correct answer has already been given, but your constructor is also strange. It first initialises your members to some hard-coded values, then assigns the real ones. Why doesn't it initialise them to the real ones?

Comment: The answer is correct, but you really shouldn't do this. For the built in `*=` operator this is Undefined Behaviour (no sequence point). In your case the function call introduces a sequence point so it works OK, but it will mislead the reader and it's not best practice.

Comment: @Christian Hackl thanks so much for your guidance and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(p7 *= 2) *= 3;
```

won't work since you're assigning to a temporary, as you return by value in the `operator*=` function.

For the sub-expression

```
p7 *= 2
```

your operator function is called only for its side-effect, as the temporary it returns would be thrown away. To know more about temporaries, read [What are C++ temporaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130338/183120) and [Temporary objects - when are they created, how do you recognise them in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10897799/183120)

When you want *expression chaining*, you've to return by reference like so

```
Position& Position::operator*= (int multi)
{
    x = x * multi;
    y = y * multi;
    z = z * multi;

    return *this;    
}
```

**Aside:** You don't have to pass built-in types by const reference(`const int &multi`), non-const copy (`int multi`) should do fine.

Comment: You probably mean "primitive types", not "POD", if by "POD" you mean structs with only public member variables.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Aah, right, thanks for bringing it up.