# QMap iterate foreach

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

Is it possible to iterate through qmap when key and value is a pointer with foreach?

I always get the error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function

```
template <typename T, typename T1>
bool func(T1* subject, QMap<T*,T1*>* map)
{
    //...
    foreach (T1* a, map->values) {

    }
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: have you tried map->values() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517853/iterating-over-a-qmap-with-for/8529237 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mike pointed out, you need to call `map->values()` before `foreach` would even work normally.

`foreach` operates on references, and `QMap::values()` returns a list of them. This would work:

```
foreach (T1 a, map->values()) {
    if (a == *subject)
        ...
}
```

Comment: i forgot the () its working also with not dereferencing it.