# Accessing iterators in a range for loop (c++11)

Tags: c++11, for-loop, iterator

Can I use the range for-loop to access the actual iterators instead of the value_type of a container?

Sample code of what I want to do (does not compile, as x is pair ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

std::map<int, float> v;

int main()
{
   for(auto x : v)    
       cout<<x->first<<", "<<x->second<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no (not unless the items in the container are iterators, and you just want to access them).

Comment: As a side note, you might want to take `x` by const reference (`const auto&`) instead of non-const value (`auto`).

Comment: thanks guys - I just wanted to keep the example simple, my case is a bit more complicated than that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Range based loop with iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953128/range-based-loop-with-iterators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the range-based for loop abstracts away from iterators. Nevertheless, in your case, you just have to change `->` to `.`:

```
for(auto x : v)    
    cout<<x.first<<", "<<x.second<<endl;
```

The range-based `for` loop exists so that you don't have to deal with iterators. If you do need iterators, you have to write the loop manually, but the actual code is not that much longer:

```
for (auto it = begin(v), ite = end(v); it != ite; ++it)
  //loop body
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with an appropriate container adaptor which wraps iterators such that `operator*()` returns the iterator instead of the value.

I think boost comes with such a wrapper.

Maybe not.  But I did find one here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920606/103167

And indeed, as Xeo observed, it can be done with Boost, since `counting_range` performs arithmetic, it works on iterators just as nicely as integers:

```
for (auto it : boost::counting_range(v.begin(), v.end()))
```