# Is it possible to compare two element in vector cycle realised as for(int a : vec)

Tags: c++

I do have a question. 
I want to do a comparison of vector elements. If I write it with an old-style

```
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size()-1; i++){
if(vec[i] < vec[i+1])
...
}
```

But with new style I can't understand, how can do the same

```
for(auto a : vect)
```

is there any way to do the same job as above?
Thank you

Comment: I guess you meant `vec.size() - 1`? No, not really, the above version is far better for that problem.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, it is out of range, I just wanted to demonstrate my problem. Thank you I will edit the question

Comment: There are some ways to get iterators in range-based for loop using boost so you could increment iterator to get next element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859348/have-range-based-for-loop-start-at-point-in-vector, but that seems pretty hard way to get what you want. I think it's better not to use "new style" here.

Comment: You can write `for (const auto& a : vect) if ((&a != &vect.back()) && (a < *(&a+1))) ...`, but it's so ugly that I definitely wouldn't use it ;). Also, it is inefficient, since there is an additional comparison in each iteration.

Comment: Actually, `vec.size() - 1` results in `SIZE_MAX` if `vec.size() == 0`, which causes invalid memory access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct style would be to use the appropriate [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) for the task at hand. You should use the range-for loop only when you want to do a

```
for (auto const & i : v) // std::for_each
```

or a

```
for (auto & i : v) // std::transform
```

In this case, if you want to compare adjacent elements, you should use one of the `std::adjacent...` algorithms.

If you just want to find a position in the vector according to a predicate that compares adjacent elements, use

```
std::adjacent_find(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

If you want to transform a range according to a predicate that uses adjacent elements, use

```
std::adjacent_difference(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v));
```

You should use a conventional for-loop only when there isn't an appropriate algorithm you can use (this happens quite rarely).

On a side note, your conventional for-loop has UB if the input range is empty. With `-Wall` the compiler will point out the problematic code. Prefer to write it like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(vec.size()) - 1; ++i){
  if(vec[i] < vec[i+1])
  // ...
}
```

Or like this, if you want to avoid casting

```
for(auto i = 0u; i + 1 < vec.size(); ++i){
  if(vec[i] < vec[i+1])
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < vec.size(); ++i)` avoids casting.

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might do:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6};

for (auto p : ranges::view::zip(v, v | ranges::view::drop(1))
              | ranges::view::filter([](auto p){ return std::get<0>(p) < std::get<1>(p); })) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(p) << " " << std::get<1>(p) << std::endl;   
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5f4146c4ecbf223)

[Ranges from C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) doesn't provide `zip` unfortunately.