# Get index in range-based for loop for sequential containers in c++11

Tags: c++11, go

I have seen following snippet in Go.
Getting index while doing range based for loop.

```
var pow = []int{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128}

for i, v := range pow {
    fmt.Printf("2**%d = %d\n", i, v)
}
```

Is there any such provision in c++11 in range-based for loop? I know having a variable and incrementing is an option, but this is more powerful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find position of element in C++11 range-based for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962290/find-position-of-element-in-c11-range-based-for-loop)

Comment: That, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953128/need-iterator-when-using-ranged-based-for-loops

Comment: no, the question - is there an equivalent in Go to range-for from C++11 .

Comment: You could take a look at range-v3 at github, maybe there will be something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Boost has a very nice range adaptor [indexed](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html):

```
  #include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
  std::vector<std::string> list = {"boost", "adaptors", "are", "great"};
  for (auto v: list | boost::adaptors::indexed(1)) {
    printf("%ld: %s\n", v.index(), v.value().c_str());
  }
```

The output:

```
1: boost
2: adaptors
3: are
4: great
```

Here we index from 1 (`boost::adaptors::indexed(1)`), but we could easily index from 0 or any other value also.